# Find $K_{3,4}$ subgraph in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm trying to find $K_{3,4}$ subgraph in the following graph:

[image]

I'm trying for hours however I can't find it. Can you please help me?

Comment: Why do you think there is one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can partition the vertices of the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,4}$ into two disjoint sets: $V_4$ that consists of the three vertices of degree $4$ and $V_3$ that consists of the four vertices of degree $3$.

Now label the eight vertices of the graph pictured in the question clockwise starting from the top: $N$, $NE$, $E$, $SE$, $S$, $SW$, $W$ and $NW$. Note that $N$, $E$, $S$ and $W$ have degree $3$ and $NE$, $SE$, $SW$ and $NW$ have degree $5$. Therefore, every vertex in $V_4$ can only be mapped to one of $NE$, $SE$, $SW$ and $NW$.

Choose any three of $NE$, $SE$, $SW$ and $NW$ and call this set $U_4$. Now, note that the vertices in $U_4$ form a triangle. This means that for each $v \in U_4$ two out of its five edges connect to another vertex in $U_4$. This leaves only three edges to connect to vertices outside of $U_4$. Therefore $U_4$ cannot correspond to $V_4$.

Consequently, $K_{3,4}$ cannot be found in the pictured graph.

Comment: But if there isn't $K_{3,4}$, how else would you justify that crossing number is 2?

Comment: A graph may have crossing number two and fail to contain $K_{3,4}$. For example, [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) has crossing number two, but does not contain $K_{3,4}$. If you're trying to prove the graph above has crossing number two, then you need a different approach.

Comment: How else would I prove that it has a crossing number 2? I know how to prove the upper bound but not the lower bound.

Comment: This is a new question unrelated to finding $K_{3,4}$, so you should really submit it separately. This would give you the benefit of other people verifying the answers. However, since it's easy I'll try to fit a sketch in a comment.

Comment: It's clear that $cr(G)\ge 1$ since $G$ contains a $K_{3,3}$. Now, let $G_e$ denote the graph obtained from $G$ by removing the edge $e$. Suppose that $cr(G)=1$. Then there exists an edge $e$ such that $G_e$ is planar. However, it's easy to check that for every edge $e$, $G_e$ contains a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$. Thus, $cr(G)$ cannot be $1$ and so $cr(G) \ge 2$. Since we can draw $G$ with only two intersections, we conclude that $cr(G)=2$.